# Binding TabControl to seperate views based on property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

#### Background:

I am trying to bind a tab control to a lot of different views using an interface for the ItemSource.

I was able to successfully do this using just

```
<Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl x:Name="ModuleTabControl"
                                               ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}">
        <Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MainPageViewModel}">
                <Views:MainPageView/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ALDViewModel}">
                <Views:ALDView/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:PumpingViewModel}">
                <Views:PumpingView/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:VerticalFlowPondViewModel}">
                <Views:VerticalFlowPondView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl.Resources>
        <Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding Header}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl>
```

where Controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl is just like a normal tab control.

This method worked for me when I was only binding to a property of `ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> TabItems` however I now feel as if instead of holding a collection of ViewModels that it is better for me to have an interface as such which I will inherit from

```
public interface ITabItem
{
    ViewModelBase ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

and those inherited classes will be stored in the collection of

`ObservableCollection<ITabItem> TabItems`

I managed to get the Header to display by changing the `{Binding Header}` with 
`{Binding ViewModel.Header}` and that works.

#### Question:

How would I link up the DataType property to the TabItems ViewModel Property where I use `{x:Type ViewModels:ALDViewModel}` ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how exactly are you going to use your interface and how it will be related to your ViewModel classes. Either there is not enough info, or you probably not working with interfaces properly. Why would you store view model instance inside an interface? That makes no sense to me, since your view model should implement this interface, not be stored inside.

So, basically, if your ViewModels are going to implement mentioned
   ITabItem, your code should work as it is, since actual
   types in your TabItems collection will stay the same. Let me
   demonstrate.

Say, you previously had something like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> TabItems { get; set; }

// add view model to collection
TabItems.Add(new ALDViewModel());
```

After using interfaces, it will end up to this:

```
// view model now implements interface
public class ALDViewModel : ViewModelBase, ITabItem

public ObservableCollection<ITabItem> TabItems { get; set; }
TabItems.Add(new ALDViewModel());
```

And since DataTempltes defined in XAML basically telling your TabControl how to display types, and your types (view models) stay the same, no changes needed.

If, however, some other type will implement interface and store view model inside and you want to bind to that view model... Well, as I mentioned, that makes no sense and it is not how you should be dealing with view models and interfaces.

I'm not sure about your scenario, but if you want to move some common logic concerning tabcontrol to separate place, you could create, say, TabViewModel class where all general logic for tabs is stored. It may look like this:

```
 /// <summary>
/// Common class for all tab viewmodels
/// </summary>
public abstract class TabViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Tab name showed to the user
    /// </summary>
    private string tabName;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the tab name
    /// </summary>
    public string TabName
    {
        get
        {
            return tabName;
        }
        set
        {
            tabName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

And then use it like this:

```
public class ALDViewModel: TabViewModel    

public ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> TabItems { get; set; }

TabViewModel aldTab = new ALDViewModel();
aldTab.TabName = "ALD";
TabItems.Add(aldTab);
```

Then again, your XAML code should stay the same and it is probably most effective way to deal with tabs in MVVM.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more clear, I have several classes that inherit ITabItem and the `ObservableCollection<ITabItem> TabItems` holds these classes

Comment: @BossmanT Thank you for the edit, but it still not exactly clear. What kind of classes inherit from ITabItem? View models? Then why you store view model inside interface? If not view models, then why they inherit from ITabItem in the first place? Pls give more details, more detailed code example of inheritance would be great.